# Create interface to C function pointers in Rust

Tags: c, rust

I might not have described my question title properly, please edit it if needed.

I'm trying to crate a Rust interface to [LXC library](https://github.com/lxc/lxc/blob/master/src/lxc/lxccontainer.h), which is written in C.

I have successfully called simple functions like `lxc_get_version` or `lxc_container_new` but I cannot get access to functions described in `struct lxc_container` block.

Here is an part of my code:

```
#[link(name = "lxc")]
extern {
    // LXC part
    fn lxc_get_version() -> *const c_char;
    fn lxc_container_new(name: *const c_char, configpath: *const c_char) -> LxcContainer;

    // LXC container parts
    fn is_defined(container: &LxcContainer) -> bool; 
}
```

And here is an error:

```
note: test.o: In function `LxcContainer::is_defined::heb2f16a250ac7940Vba':
test.0.rs:(.text._ZN12LxcContainer10is_defined20heb2f16a250ac7940VbaE+0x3e): undefined reference to `is_defined'
```

**EDIT:** I have managed that functions inside C structs is called function pointers. I've tried to google something like "Rust C function pointer", but without luck.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you see something like this (in C):

```
struct S {
    void (*f)(int, long)
}
```

it means that struct `S` contains a field called `f` which is a pointer to a function. It does not mean that the library itself exposes a function called `f`. For example, this is valid:

```
void some_function_1(int x, long y) { ... }

void some_function_2(int a, long b) { ... }

int main() {
    struct S s1; s1.f = some_function_1;
    struct S s2; s2.f = some_function_2;
}
```

Here struct instance `s1` contains a pointer to `some_function_1`, and `s2` contains a pointer to `some_function_2`.

When you're writing FFI binding in Rust for some C library, you usually define Rust counterparts for C structures. Some tools like `rust-bindgen` can even do this automatically. In your case you will have to write something like this:

```
#[repr(C)]
struct LxcContainer {
    name: *mut c_char,
    configfile: *mut c_char,
    // ...
    numthreads: c_int,
    // ...
    is_defined_f: extern fn(c: *mut LxcContainer) -> bool,
    state_f: extern fn(c: *mut LxcContainer) -> *const c_char,
    // ...
}
```

That is, weird-looking C function pointer types correspond to `extern fn` function pointer types in Rust. You could also write `extern "C" fn(...) -> ...`, but `"C"` qualifier is default so it is not required.

You will have to write something like this to call these functions:

```
impl LxcContainer {
    fn is_defined_f(&mut self) -> bool {
        unsafe {
            (self.is_defined_f)(self as *mut LxcContainer)
        }
    }
}
```

You need to cast a reference to a raw pointer and you also need to wrap `self.is_defined_f` in parentheses in order to disambiguate between method call and field access.

You can find more on FFI in Rust [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html). Function pointers are explained very briefly there, though.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I can now get access to function pointers. I have wrote a struct for C representation and a wrapper for Rust representation around it. Unfortunately I cannot make a call to `is_defined` because I cannot pass LxcContainer struct to function as *LxcContainer. Dereference error occurs. Could you please add some example of function pointer calling into your answer?  Thank you.

Comment: @bbrodriges, sorry for the late reply, but I have updated my answer with an example of how to call functions stored in struct fields.