# How to wrap multi-threaded callbacks in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, callback, rust

I'm struggling with my [soundio crate](https://crates.io/crates/soundio), which is a wrapper for [libsoundio](https://github.com/andrewrk/libsoundio). If you want to play a .wav file, the C library requires you to pass a callback function when you open the output stream. That callback is called in a loop *in another thread*, and you output the samples in it.

I can do it like this:

```
struct WavPlayer {
    reader: hound::WavReader<BufReader<File>>,
}

impl WavPlayer {
    fn write_callback(&mut self, stream: &mut soundio::OutStreamWriter) {
        // Copy samples from `self.reader` to `stream`.
    }
}

// In main():
    let mut player = WavPlayer {
        reader: ...,
    };

    let mut output_stream = output_dev.open_outstream(
        ...
        |x| player.write_callback(x),
    )?;
```

The parameter to `open_outstream()` is `FnMut(&mut OutStreamWriter)`.

The problem is that `output_dev` takes ownership of `WavPlayer` and then you can't control it or monitor it any more. When the wav file ends it is really difficult to tell the main program to exit, and there's no way I can easily pause or seek it. What I really want is an interface like this:

```
trait SoundPlayer {
    fn play(&mut self);
    fn stop(&mut self);
    fn seek(&mut self, pos: Duration);
    fn position(&self) -> Duration;

    fn get_write_callback(&self) -> &FnMut(&mut soundio::OutStreamWriter);
}
```

However, I cannot work out what combination of `Mutex`, `RefCell`, `Arc`, etc. I need for the callback. I must need shared ownership of *something* because I need access to the `SoundPlayer` from `main()` and (indirectly, via the callback) from `output_dev`, so I guess there must be an `Arc` in there somewhere.

And I'll need interior mutability because I really want to be able to call `play()` while `output_dev` still has a reference to the player.

[Here is my current code](https://github.com/Timmmm/soundio-rs/blob/master/examples/player/main.rs) that works, but doesn't quit when the file ends and you can't pause or seek.

I'm a bit lost here. I know I could use `mpsc` to send samples but that seems like a cop-out.

Comment: nitpick: https://github.com/Timmmm/soundio-rs/blob/master/libsoundio-sys/lib.rs#L321 you should use `Option<extern fn (...)>`, not `*mut extern fn (...)`. The `fn` type is already a function pointer, adding `*mut` makes it a double-pointer. The `Option<>` makes it nullable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117197/create-interface-to-c-function-pointers-in-rust and https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html#the-nullable-pointer-optimization

Comment: Ah nice catch. Presumably that applies to `write_callback` and so on too? But why does it work at all if I'm passing double-pointers?

Comment: Actually never mind, the binary FFI is still ok-ish because a pointer is still a pointer, and I am just casting to `*mut _` wherever I use it. I will fix all those - thanks!

Comment: Hmm, could you write a minimal example that can be compiled in the playground? That would make it much easier to experiment and write a good answer.

Comment: "I must need shared ownership of something" - you can't pass a reference to a scoped thread?

Comment: @user4815162342: Good idea, I will do that.

Comment: @the8472: Maybe. I'm not sure this works if the thread is created by the C library. Anyway I'll make a more minimal test case and then we can see.